# website font stop working after upload on different server

Tags: css, apache, fonts, server, font-face

I recently build a website for my client, and got a problem. Everything works fine when I upload on my server (apache), but when my client upload it on to his server (I don't know what OS yet), the fonts stop working correctly. The same files, same code, regardless of browser. Any ideas?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'xxx';
src: url('xxx.eot');
src: url('xxx.eot?‪#‎iefix‬') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('xxx.woff') format('woff'),
url('xxx.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('xxx.svg#xxx') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Could have something to do with mime-types set up on their server.

Comment: you realize you have to upload the font file to the new server as well, right? have you added `xxx.eot`, `xxx.woff`, `xxx.ttf`, and `xxx.svg` to the new server?

Comment: yes, of course, we check that first - files are fine

Comment: what does the console say? is the site live anywhere?

Comment: I don't have access to my client server, so I can't check the console. I think it's about  server setting which is messed up. Server support should help this i think...

Comment: I mean use the in-browser console, when the page is loaded. It will show you if the font is loaded or not.

Comment: console 2 errors:
http://trzydewizje.com/ud/font/SegoeCondensed.woff Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

/
http://trzydewizje.com/ud/font/SegoeCondensed.ttf Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: as I said earlier, the files are uploaded correctly

Comment: @tyma92 did my answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found your problem: http://trzydewizje.com/ud/font/.

> `trzydewizje.com/ud/font/SegoeCondensed.woff` Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> `trzydewizje.com/ud/font/SegoeCondensed.ttf` Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[image: Errors]

At least in the errors you posted in the comments, you are trying to link to `SegoeCondensed.woff`, while the actual files are all lowercase like `segoecondensed.woff`.

To verify this, I visited your stylesheet where the fonts are added(http://trzydewizje.com/ud/font/stylesheet.css), and that seems to be the problem:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Segoe Condensed';
    src: url('SegoeCondensed.eot');
    src: url('SegoeCondensed.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('SegoeCondensed.woff') format('woff'),
        url('SegoeCondensed.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('SegoeCondensed.svg#SegoeCondensed') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I checked this by editing the css in-browser, and changing the file names fixed your problem:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Segoe Condensed';
    src: url('segoecondensed.eot');
    src: url('segoecondensed.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('segoecondensed.woff') format('woff'),
        url('segoecondensed.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('segoecondensed.svg#SegoeCondensed') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: haha that was it. The program my client use to upload files, has change the letters  in files names. Thanks ;)